# Carrying out a search using a for loop using Boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, search

I want to carry out a search on a list that consists of numbers. The program goes through the list and returns True (boolean) if number found and False if number not found.

```
found = False
numlist=[1,6,9,24,92,42]
for i in numlist:
    if i==92:
        found=True
        break
    print(found,i)
print(found)
if found=True:
    print("desired value found")
else:
    print("value not found")
```

The program indicates an error on line 9. Could someone please explain what mistake I have made and any suggestions to make the code more efficient

Comment: change `if found=True:` to either `if found==True:` or `if found:`

Comment: `found = 92 in numList` can replace the `for` loop.

Comment: @MustafaAydın interesting…could you please elaborate a bit more if possible.

Comment: @AllmdarArslan The Pythonic way to check whether a value is in a list or not is via the `in` operator. It also iterates over the list but that's all under the hood and not exposed to the user at all. It returns a boolean: `True` if found, `False` otherwise. (This `in` is resolved to [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).)

Comment: Alternatively to the use of the `in` operator, you could use Numpy for big arrays. Working on Numpy array can be much faster thanks to vectorization and well-defined fixed-types per array (while list can hold dynamically-typed items preventing many optimizations).